# How To Update Random ID to a table in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have table like this:

```
ID | City     | Prize |
----------------------------
1  |Surabaya  | HP
2  |Surabaya  | Watch 
3  |Surabaya  | Bag
4  |Semarang  |
5  |Semarang  |Watch
6  |Semarang  |
7  |Bandung   |
8  |Bandung   |
9  |Bandung   |
```

---

My Question is How to creat Update Query for Fill The Prize column where City = '(already in settings)' AND ID =  Random.

ex: I want Update to fill Watch in City = 'Bandung' But ID = 'random' maybe (7,8,9).

I Hope you know What I Mean.

Im Very Apreciated your Advice

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple solution is to materialize the result of the query that identifies the row to update, and fetch that result with a scalar subquery...

```
UPDATE table_name
   SET prize = 'Watch'
 WHERE id = (SELECT * 
               FROM ( SELECT id 
                        FROM table_name 
                       WHERE City = 'Bandung' 
                         AND (Prize != 'Watch' OR Prize IS NULL)
                       ORDER BY RAND()
                       LIMIT 1 ) dt1
             );
```

This selects a random id FROM the table from the desired set of rows, materializes that as a derived table with the alias `dt1` with one row and one column (the id of the new winner), and then selects that id using a subquery and uses it in the outer where clause to update the row.

There's no chance of 0 rows affected unless everybody already has a watch because we selected the "randomly first" id from among the list of potential winners.

Comment: I think you want `AND (Prize != 'Watch' OR Prize IS NULL)`

Comment: @ypercube if the column is nullable, you're absolutely correct.  I made the assumption that it wasn't, based on what looked like empty strings in the question, but the additional test is valid with either option in the column definition, so +1 ...updated.

Comment: @Michael - sqlbot Great. thats What I Need. :) Thanks

Comment: Any update order by rand() or id=rand() is replication unsafe if you have statement based replication. Hope your are not having that level complex stuff. But if you have a replication, do a select for update followed by update statement.

Comment: @cjg +1 that's true if you you're using `STATEMENT` mode; however, if `ROW` or `MIXED` then this query will be logged correctly since using `RAND()` will trip the internal logic to flag the query unsafe for statement logging and cause any query involving it to be logged as a row event.   Using `binlog_format=STATEMENT`, it will throw an "unsafe" warning, which some clients ignore.  Statement mode [has so many potential problems](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-sbr-rbr.html) that I *never* use it and didn't stop to consider that it is still, almost inexplicably, the default.

Answer (score 1):

```
update Table1 t1
Inner join
(Select * from Table1 where City = 'Bandung' 
 Order by Rand()limit 1) t2
on t1.ID = t2.ID
Set t1.Prize = 'Watch';
```

**[Sample fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94495/1)**

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table-name SET Prize = "Watch" 
    WHERE City = "Bandung" 
    AND ID = ROUND((9-7)*RAND()) + 7
```

Comment: Makasih Mas,  0 row affected.  ID nya tu detek berdasarkan Kota misal bandung 6-9 maka yg dirandom itu ya 6-9. kalau Surabaya misal 1-5 ya yang dirandom 1-5. bisa nggak Mas?

Answer (score 0):

You want to only update 1 value at a time right?

In order to UPDATE existing values, you will need to generate a table with the possible values and a selectable value, something like a counter, which I added into the @table. The reason for this is you might not always have sequential IDs with no prizes.
Take 'Semarang' as an example of this. So we force a sequence by using IDENTITY.

We will then select a random number against the IDENTITY column in order to always select an existing value.

```
DECLARE @prizetable TABLE (ID INT, City VARCHAR(50), Prize VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @prizetable VALUES
(1,'Surabaya', 'HP'),(2,'Surabaya', 'Watch' )
,(3,'Surabaya', 'Bag'),(4,'Semarang','')
,(5,'Semarang','Watch'),(6,'Semarang','')
,(7,'Bandung',''),(8,'Bandung','')
,(9,'Bandung',''),(10,'Bandung','')
,(11,'Bandung',''),(12,'Bandung',''),(13,'Bandung','');

DECLARE @CityToDo VARCHAR(50) = 'Bandung';
/*Lets do a driver table, adding a counter so that you can do a RAND select against existing numbers*/
DECLARE @needsprize TABLE (Counter INT IDENTITY(0,1), ID INT);
INSERT INTO @needsprize
SELECT p.ID
FROM @prizetable p
WHERE (p.Prize IS NULL OR LEN(p.Prize) < 1)
AND City = @CityToDo;

/*This will give your RAND a ceiling, else you will update nothing most of the time*/
DECLARE @RANDceiling INT = (SELECT MAX(Counter) FROM @needsprize);
DECLARE @RANDnumber INT = (SELECT ROUND(RAND ()*(@RANDceiling) ,0));

UPDATE p
SET p.Prize ='Watch This'
FROM @prizetable p
INNER JOIN @needsprize np ON np.ID = p.ID 
WHERE (p.Prize IS NULL OR LEN(p.Prize) < 1)
AND City = @CityToDo
AND np.Counter = @RANDnumber;

SELECT * 
FROM @prizetable
```

**EDIT**

There is no simple function to to what you want, unless you don't mind *(0 row(s) affected)*
all the time.

Let me explain more. You want to look at 'Semarang' for this.

```
ID  City        Prize
4   Semarang    
5   Semarang    Watch
6   Semarang
```

You need to look at ID 4 and 6 in order to give a prize. 5 already has a prize.

You *SELECT RANDOM NUMBER* it returns a 157862, no updates will be made as the number is outside of the range.

You *SELECT RANDBETWEEN 4 and 6* it returns 5, no updates will be made.

So now you take the IDs that need updating and you add a sequence number to them. So lets to a direct Update, you will still need some type of staging table, so lets use a CTE

```
/*This will simulate your table*/
DECLARE @prizetable TABLE (ID INT, City VARCHAR(50), Prize VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @prizetable VALUES
(1,'Surabaya', 'HP'),(2,'Surabaya', 'Watch' )
,(3,'Surabaya', 'Bag'),(4,'Semarang','')
,(5,'Semarang','Watch'),(6,'Semarang','')
,(7,'Bandung',''),(8,'Bandung','')
,(9,'Bandung',''),(10,'Bandung','')
,(11,'Bandung',''),(12,'Bandung',''),(13,'Bandung','');

DECLARE @CityToDo VARCHAR(50) = 'Bandung';


WITH TempPrizeTable AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) AS RowNumber, p.ID
    FROM @prizetable p
    WHERE (p.Prize IS NULL OR LEN(p.Prize) < 1)
    AND City = @CityToDo
) 
UPDATE p
SET p.Prize ='Watch This'
FROM @prizetable p
INNER JOIN TempPrizeTable tp ON tp.ID = p.ID
WHERE tp.RowNumber = (SELECT ROUND(RAND ()*(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TempPrizeTable),0));

SELECT * FROM @prizetable
```

Comment: Thanks For Your Explanation, but I Still Not UnderStand. I Just Need maybe A function or something that Can random the ID before Update it.

Comment: Please see EDIT, you cannot simply use a function. A function like RAND will return a number that will be out of the range of your list of IDs.

Comment: The question is tagged with "mysql". How can `IDENTITY`, CTEs and `ROW_NUMBER()` help - from which MySQL has none?